# dbus-1 gcc error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'struct'

Tags: c

I am trying to compile dbus-1 in a project using mingw32-gcc, I get a compiler error

```
 error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'struct'.
```

As far as I can tell, the line in question is a function call. this is an excerpt from the makefile log:

```
` c:/MinGW/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-message.h:73:95: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'struct'
 DBusMessage* dbus_message_new_method_call(const char *bus_name, const char    *path, const char *interface ,const char *method);`
```

here is the  excerpt from the dbus-message.h header file:

```
#if !defined (DBUS_INSIDE_DBUS_H) && !defined (DBUS_COMPILATION)
#error "Only <dbus/dbus.h> can be included directly, this file may disappear     or change contents."
#endif

#ifndef DBUS_MESSAGE_H
#define DBUS_MESSAGE_H

#include <dbus/dbus-macros.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-types.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-memory.h>
#include <dbus/dbus-errors.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

DBUS_BEGIN_DECLS

/**
 * @addtogroup DBusMessage
 * @{
 */

 typedef struct DBusMessage DBusMessage;
/** Opaque type representing a message iterator. Can be copied by value, and   contains no allocated memory so never needs to be freed and can be allocated on the stack. */
 typedef struct DBusMessageIter DBusMessageIter;

 /**
  * DBusMessageIter struct; contains no public fields. 
  */
  struct DBusMessageIter
 { 
   void *dummy1;         /**< Don't use this */
   void *dummy2;         /**< Don't use this */
   dbus_uint32_t dummy3; /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy4;           /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy5;           /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy6;           /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy7;           /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy8;           /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy9;           /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy10;          /**< Don't use this */
   int dummy11;          /**< Don't use this */
   int pad1;             /**< Don't use this */
   int pad2;             /**< Don't use this */
   void *pad3;           /**< Don't use this */
  };

 DBUS_EXPORT
 DBusMessage* dbus_message_new               (int          message_type);
 DBUS_EXPORT

 DBusMessage* dbus_message_new_method_call(const char *bus_name, const char *path, const char *interface ,const char *method);
```

I couldnt figure out why the compiler thinks interface is a struct. from looking at the c source and the other headers it seems like a char string pointer.

any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever line 73 is, check round *prior* to that and look for a missing semi-colon.

Comment: Suggestion: expand macros manually to see what the "actual" c code will be if the error / line number makes no sense. Macros often are a source of syntax errors especially if you're going to do things like `DBUS_BEGIN_DECLS` and hiding slabs of inline code with macros.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code you provided is is the entire header file. But, if so it looks like you are missing an #endif for #ifndef DBUS_MESSAGE_H header guard. Try putting #endif at the end of your file.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I found another dbus distribution on www.freedesktop.org that has files that were not in the the distribution I had. Apparently in the code I had, struct DBusMessage was never defined  in any of the files. in dbus-1 10.8  distribution there are several other header files, in particular dbus-message-private.h that defines the struct. The code now compiles ok.